# ExtJS - Custom JSON structure from getFormValues

Tags: extjs

Been searching on the web & can't seem to find an answer that is suitable and hoping someone has faced the issue where you need to change the structure of the ExtJS `getFormValues` response type to the structure you controller expects.

For example

```
form.a = "I'm A"
form.b = "I'm B"
form.c = "I'm C"
```

The JSON from the `getFieldValues()` are:

```
"fom_name":{
  "a": "I'm A",
  "b": "I'm B",
  "c": "I'm C"
}
```

However, what I need for the controller structure is

```
{
    "form_name": {
        "nestedArray": [{
            "a": "I'm A",
            "b": "I'm B",
            "c": "I'm C"
        }],
        "array2": []
    }
}
```

I know I can iterator over the fieldvalues & change them on the fly to fit the structure but looking for a generic solution that can do this for me.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Ian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I can iterator over the fieldvalues & change them on the fly to
>   fit the structure

I would probably just do this since it seems fairly trivial and I don't think there is a simpler way to do this. You can include it as an override if you want ([Ext.form.Basic.getFieldValues](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-getFieldValues)):

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.Basic, {
    getFieldValues: function(dirtyOnly) {

        //return this.getValues(false, dirtyOnly, false, true);

        var vals = this.getValues(false, dirtyOnly, false, true);

        var output = {};
        //iterate through vals and structure it the way you want it
        return output;
    },
});
```